# How to use Next.js Link with multiple children?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to use `Link` in Next.js with multiple `<div>` inside this `<div>`? I have img tag for `Link`, paragraph for link , title for link.

> Error: Multiple children were passed to  with `href` of
> `/article` but only one child is supported
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children  Open your
> browser's console to view the Component stack trace.

```
<Link href="/article" title="">
      <div >
          <h4>{props.featurename}</h4>
          <a href="/author"><h3>{props.featuredesc}</h3></a>
      </div>
      <div className="img-entry">
          <Image src="/images/more-img.png" width={265} height={290} title="" alt="" />
      </div>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use fragments in order to group multiple element under one main child that won't be visible in the tree. (https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

```
      <Link ***href***="/article" title="">
       <>
        <div >
          <h4>{props.featurename}</h4>
          <a href="/author"><h3>{props.featuredesc}</h3></a>
        </div>
        <div className="img-entry">
          <Image src="/images/more-img.png" width={265} height={290} title="" alt="" />
        </div>
       </>
      </Link>
```

Comment: It did not work for me.
I get:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <a>.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error